# Black Ops / MW3 differences

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-black-ops

What are the actual differences between Black Ops and MW3? I'm talking about the differences between online and offline play modes as well as differences in actual gameplay and also things like differences in perks etc. For example, bots are present in black ops for offline matches which is absent in MW3 (although there are the special ops modes).

If I were to ask a pro player the differences between the two, what would they say?

(I'm not asking for a huge list of all the actual differences between perks, just general game design)

Comment: You get Zombies in Black Ops. That's all that matters

Comment: This is a very broad question in its current form; presumably there are many differences both subtle and large between the two games. Can you narrow it down to a specific aspect of the game, such as a weapon or game mode?

Comment: Gameplay wise, they have very similiar components, it is all about the time period they are placed in.

Comment: possible (partial) duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44121/call-of-duty-mw3-guide-for-black-ops-players

Answer (score 5):

They do use different game engines. Black Ops uses a modified IW3 engine (originally used in CoD4 and WaW), while MW3 uses the IW5 engine. One of the major differences (in multiplayer) - taken from [here](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty_game_engine_mechanics) is that movement speed is determined by the currently equipped weapon in Black Ops, while it is determined by the primary weapon upon spawning in MW3.

Black Ops allows you to dive to prone while sprinting, while MW3 does not. Each game has different materials that can be penetrated by bullets.

One difference a lot of people notice/complain about is that Black Ops runs at a lower fps than the Modern Warfare series (which runs at 60 fps).

As far as offline play goes, the campaigns are obviously totally different - different styles of storytelling, different objective types. MW3 does not have Zombies, as already mentioned. Survival Mode vs. Bots in local matches is very different too. Bots allow you to play TDM/FFA against up to 9 bots for standard games. Survival Mode runs until you die - there is no end to the game.

Many people will notice different differences, so some things are obviously a matter of opinion, but these were a few changes that stand out commonly.

Answer (score 0):

Well for online and offline the survival mode and zombie mode are compatable. Here are a few things.

- Both allow purchase of grenades weapons and perks.
- Both are endless and get harder each level
- Each has its own difficulties.

Now a few differences.

- In black ops zombies tend to just fall on their knees dead or fall without ragdoll effect.
- MW3 survival has multiple enemies and several diffuculties in its maps and involves actual enemy tactics, like a riot juggernaut with a normal juggernaut one behind the riot juggernaut.